# Prevent animation of TitleView of UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, navigationbar

I'm using a `UINavigatonController` based app with a `UISegmentedControl` in the TitleView, and my problem is when I push a controller (or pop) with animated:YES it's animating the TitleView too, so my segmented control is sliding too. I want it to stay in place.

Any ideas are welcome :)
Thank you in advance!

Comment: It'd be great if you changed the question now that the solution was really to "not use `titleView`", it is misleading for those that really have the animation problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `titleView` is specific to the navigation controller's `topViewController`'s `navigationItem`. Try adding your segmented control to the navigation bar manually.

Comment: I'm adding the segmented control in every controller's viewDidLoad, because if I navigate away from the current view, the titleView will be new, so I have to add the segmented control in every controller's viewDidLoad.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm referring to. Because the `titleView` is connected to each individual view controller, you're always going to be pushing and popping new title views along with the view controllers. Don't use `titleView`. Add just one segmented control to the navigation bar.

Comment: So i have to add the segmented control as a subview of the navigationbar?

Comment: Thank you, now i'm adding the segmented control at the "beginning" with code, center it to the navigationbar's center and that's just the thing i want! :)

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

create segment control using initWithFrame and then set it to navigationItem's titleView property.